# Can't getValue inside onDataChange

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mobile

I try to get a value from my firebase real-time DB on my app but i can't use `.getValue()` to get the value of the post likes on my activity for some reason. I have try to make another reference inside on another class but i still can't use the `getValue()` method.

**A part of my code:**

```
public static void setIconToLiked(String postID) {
            likeRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                public ImageSwitcher like_btn;

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.child(postID).hasChild(HomeActivity.userID)){
                        // user has been liked this so we need to change the icon of the button to liked \\
                        like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_emoji);
                        
                        // here i can't get the value of the post likes \\
                        postRef.child(postID).child("likes").getValue().toString();
                    }else{
                        // user has not liked this post so we need to set the icon of the button to not-liked \\
                        like_btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_emoji_before);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getValue` method only on an `database reference` object